# What is the name of Ubuntu's MIDI device

Tags: python-3.x, midi

I am trying to do some MIDI programming using py-midi using the documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/py-midi/

The first step is to create a connection to the MIDI device:
(from the docs)

```
    >>> from midi import MidiConnector
    >>> conn = MidiConnector('/dev/serial0')  # path to use on RaspberryPi 3
```

I don't have an external MIDI device, so I'd like to use the one built into my computer.  I looked in /dev and /dev/snd, but I don't see a device named MIDI or similar.

What is the name of the MIDI device on Ubuntu? (I am using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

Comment: on my system my USB MIDI comes up as /dev/midi1

Comment: @FTrias If only it were so easy on my machine.  Maybe there isn't a MIDI device?

Comment: They would show up in /dev/snd/, if you had any. What particular device do you want to use? Anyway, that library appears to support only serial ports, which is not how MIDI devices are connected normally.

Comment: It's a Thinkpad laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18, the built in midi device is /dev/snd/seq